# What PHP/Perl CMS for a corporate site?

Tags: php, .net, perl, content-management-system

I am going to create a corporate site with around 150-200 pages. Several pages have three category levels (I mean a URL like products/myproduct/overview)

The client's employees should be able to edit all the pages very easily, manage the navigation and left blocks as well.

What CMS (opensource, if possible) can I use? PHP, Perl would be good but I am open to .NET if necessary.

Thanks!
Dav3

Answer (score 3):

A list of Perl CMS's can be found under [`applications`](http://www.perlfoundation.org/perl5/index.cgi?applications) on the [`Perl5 wiki`](http://www.perlfoundation.org/perl5/).

Also looking at your requirement you may find a Wiki to be an option?  In particular [`MojoMojo`](http://www.mojomojo.org/) because this differs from the standard wiki approach by allowing directory structures thus making your category levels `products/myproduct/overview` possible.

/I3az/

Answer (score 2):

**Perl:** if you're happy coding up the admin backend and (possibly) have used [CGI::Application](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/cgi-application), Mark Strosberg's [Titanium](http://mark.stosberg.com/blog/2008/12/titanium-a-new-release-and-more.html) framework is nippy and lightweight but as powerful as you need it to be or - if you want something more popular - try [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/). For an example (can't show the backend, which uses Markdown) [this site is built on Titanium](http://emaran.org/).

**PHP:** If you don't want to code up the backend a CMS is the way to go. The latest version of [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/) should do what you want, although you'll probably have to hobble the WYSIWYG editor and editing options (and provide a little training) to prevent users from doing (say) things like pasting an entire Word document into the editing window! For an example (again, can't show backend) [this site uses the latest version of Joomla](http://vision2020.org.uk).

But everyone's going to have their favourites here...

Answer (score 2):

[Bricolage 2](http://www.bricolagecms.org/) - You'll get permissions, alerts, ldap authentication, publishing process, and a whole bunch of great features with it. Or if you'd rather write the whole thing by yourself, use [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org/).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go with a PHP CMS then I can only recommend Drupal.

http://drupal.org/

Answer (score 0):

[Cyclone3](http://www.cyclone3.org/) CMS is very interesting, including GUI based on Firefox.

Answer (score -1):

Going with Perl Catalyst will be good.

In PHP I would recommend using SilverStripe CMS:http://silverstripe.org/

Its powerful and easy to extend.

Comment: Not sure what's up with the Catalyst suggestions - Catalyst is a web framework, not a CMS.